# Is there an existing wordpress plugin for in post, 1 pic per page, multi-page galleries?

Tags: wordpress, pagination, gallery

I'm looking to add gallery functionality to a wordpress site for a client. They want functionality to be similar to what you see here:

http://www.thefrisky.com/post/246-celebrate-national-ice-cream-month-with-mail-order-treats/

Where each post could be split into x amount of pages. Each with a photo, caption, blurb and an in-post navigation (prev, next, "x of y" text).

Is there an existing wordpress plugin to handle this kind of thing or if not, how would you suggest handling it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any plugins to do that for you, but you can do it manually with the WordPress `<!--nextpage-->` tag.  Switch to code view for the post and insert it where you want the page breaks:

```
First page's content
<!--nextpage-->
Second page's content
<!--nextpage-->
Third page's content
```

Comment: awesome, thanks! i also found this plugin (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multi-page-toolkit/installation/) which builds off that core wordpress nextpage functionality to change the page nav options to things like "3 of 5" and use next and previous links. was able to tweak the plugin as needed. thanks for pointing me in the right direction.